# + and - to show and hide sub lists

Tags: jquery

I'm working on showing a conversation thread, for each comment there is a list of comments, I show all the comments that I have and the sub comments but would like to add (+) and (-) to allow the user to show just the sub comments he/she needs, but I'm having some trouble to do that. Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class='limit'>
        <div class='comment'>
            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un commentaire statique 1</div>
            <div class='content'>Qui cum venisset ob haec festinatis itineribus Antiochiam, praestrictis palatii ianuis, contempto</div>
            <div class='subComments'>
                <div class='reduce'>__</div>
                <div class='reduce' style="display:none;">+</div>
                <div class='comment'>
                    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1</div>
                    <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1</div>
                    <div class='subComments'>
                        <div class='reduce'>__</div>
                        <div class='reduce' style="display:none;">+</div>
                        <div class='comment'>
                            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1.1</div>
                            <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1.1</div>
                            <div class='subComments'>
                                <div class='reduce'>__</div>
                                <div class='reduce' style="display:none;">+</div>
                                <div class='comment'>
                                    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1.1.1</div>
                                    <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1.1.1</div>
                                    <div class='subComments'>
                                        <div class='reduce'>__</div>
                                        <div class='reduce' style="display:none;">+</div>
                                        <div class='comment'>
                                            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1.1.1.1</div>
                                            <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 1.1.1.1.1</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='comment'>
                    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 1.2</div>
                    <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 1.2</div>
                    <div class='subComments'>
                        <div class='reduce'>__</div>
                        <div class='reduce' style="display:none;">+</div>
                        <div class='comment'>
                            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 1.2.1</div>
                            <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 1.2.1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div class='comment'>
            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un commentaire statique 2</div>
            <div class='content'>content d'un commentaire statique 2</div>
            <div class='subComments'>
                <div class='comment'>
                    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 2.1</div>
                    <div class='content'>content d'un commentaire statique 2.1</div>
                    <div class='subComments'>
                        <div class='comment'>
                            <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 2.1.1</div>
                            <div class='content'>content d'un sous commentaire statique 2.1.1</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class='comment'>
                    <div class='titre'>Titre d'un sous commentaire statique 2.1</div>
                    <div class='content'>content d'un commentaire statique 2.1</div>
                    <div class='subComments'></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And my JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.subComments').on('click', '.reduce', function () {
        $(".reduce").toggle("fast");
        $(this).parent().children().not('.reduce').toggle("slow");
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.limit {
    //border: solid 1px blue;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:650px;
}
.comment {
    //border: solid 1px blue;
    margin: auto;
    width: 480px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.titre {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: blue;
    padding: 12px;
}
.content {
    padding: 12px;
}
.subComments {
    border-top: solid 1px blue;
    width: 580px;
    float:left;
}
.reduce {
    font-size:1.4em;
    color: black;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You can look [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kirikou12/w58s7/) to see the problem.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Please fix the link to your jsfiddle demo.

Comment: Could you please tell me whats the problem with it??

Comment: ok I changed it :) it should work now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salut l'ami!

Does this make the job ?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.reduce', function(){ 
       $(this).toggle('fast');
       $(this).siblings().toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Here is your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w58s7/1/)

EDIT : You can even do this simpler thing :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click', '.reduce', function(){ 
       $(this).siblings().addBack().toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w58s7/3/)

Comment: Could you please tell me why it doesn't work when I put $('.subComments') instead of $('body')??

Comment: As you are using nested `.subComments` and `.reduce` DOM elements, the click event will be attached to **ALL** `.reduce` childs **AND** subchilds of **ALL** `.subcomments` elements. So, your subchilds will have the event attached several times (one for each `.subcomments` parent), and this can cause shitty behaviors ... If you use `$('body')`, you are sure that the event is attached only once per `.reduce` element. Am I clear enough ?

Comment: Good. It would have been easier using *la langue de Molière* ;)

Comment: hahah totally agree, I appreciate ur efforts :) u explained it perfectly though ;)

Answer (score 0):

I didnt really understand your problem and your html hahha but take a look at my solution.

```
//this is the sample html
<div class="comment">
    <div class="subComment">
        //sub comments goes here
    </div>
    <button name="show">+</button>
    <button name="hide">-</button>
</div>

//this is the jquery code
$(document).ready(function(){

    //for showing the sub comments
    $('button[name=show]').click(function(){
        $this.sibling('div.subComment').show();//im not so sure about using .sibling function
    });

    //for hiding the sub comments
    $('button[name=show]').click(function(){
        $this.sibling('div.subComment').show();//just tell me if .sibling didnt work
    });

});
```

Comment: haha my bad, yeas my code is a little bit long, thats y I provided the demo!
I need some time to get ur code fixed so that I could test it and tell you whether it works or not!

Comment: maybe you could just check M'sieur Toph's solution. he also has a demo hahha.